# How to merge duplicate records to a single record in dataframe Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I read a csv file to a dataframe as bellow:

| ID | StudentCode | Name | Birth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Abc001 | S-01 | John | 03/10/2000 |
| Abc002 | S-01 | John | 03/10/2000 |
| Abc003 | S-01 | John | 03/10/2000 |
| Abc004 | S-02 | Mark | 12/08/2001 |
| Abc005 | S-02 | Mark | 12/08/2001 |
| Abc006 | S-03 | Ernst | 01/10/2005 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I have tried to convert to other dataframe like:

| StudentCode | Name | Birth | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| S-01 | John | 03/10/2000 | Abc001; Abc002; Abc003 |
| S-02 | Mark | 12/08/2001 | Abc004; Abc005 |
| S-03 | Ernst | 01/10/2005 | Abc006 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

Are there methods with dataframe in Python that we can convert like above?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the [groupby](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) function?

Comment: Yes, I tried. And applied it to my code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
import io

temp = io.StringIO("""ID,StudentCode,Name,Birth
0,Abc001,S-01,John,03/10/2000
1,Abc002,S-01,John,03/10/2000
2,Abc003,S-01,John,03/10/2000
3,Abc004,S-02,Mark,12/08/2001
4,Abc005,S-02,Mark,12/08/2001
5,Abc006,S-03,Ernst,01/10/2005""")
df = pd.read_csv(temp, sep=",")

df.groupby(["StudentCode","Name","Birth","ID"]).mean()

StudentCode Name    Birth       ID
S-01        John    03/10/2000  Abc001
                                Abc002
                                Abc003
S-02        Mark    12/08/2001  Abc004
                                Abc005
S-03       Ernst    01/10/2005  Abc006
```

Comment: I tried but it not work "KeyError: 'StudentCode'"

Comment: I have edited my table with commas so it should work now.

Comment: I tried to print out the final df by using df_final = df.groupby(["StudentCode","Name","Birth","ID"]).mean()
print(df_final) but Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [(S-01, John, 03/10/2000, Abc001), (S-01, John, 03/10/2000, Abc002), (S-01, John, 03/10/2000, Abc003), (S-02, Mark, 12/08/2001, Abc004), (S-02, Mark, 12/08/2001, Abc005), (S-03, Ernst, 01/10/2005, Abc006)]

Comment: I found the solution with group = df.groupby(["StudentCode","Name","Birth"])['ID'].agg(';'.join)
print(group)